# Tkinter button been pressed and run kodi software?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to this python programming. I'm try to make a code that let tkinter button launch an external software in raspberry pi 3. Unfortunately, the button GUI been pressed but the external software or program did not launch. The external program that link with button GUI is kodi software. Is it possible to launch the kodi software when GUI button is pressed?

```
from tkinter import
import os

class Trying(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
         Frame.__init__(self, master)
         self.grid()
         self.button()

    def button(self):
         self.test = Button(self, text="Lauch", command="kodi")
         self.test.grid()

    def kodi():
         os.startfile('/usr/share/applications/kodi.desktop')

root = Tk()
root.title("test kodi")
root.geometry("150x85")

app = Trying(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fixed code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import subprocess

class Trying(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.button()

    def button(self):
        self.test = Button(self, text="Lauch", command=self.kodi)
        self.test.grid()

    def kodi(self):
        print ("Button pressed")
        subprocess.call(['kodi'])

root = Tk()
root.title("test kodi")
root.geometry("150x85")

app = Trying(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Note:

- specify button action like this `command=self.kodi`
- function kodi needs to take an argument `def kodi(self)`

Comment: thank for the correction. however,  the problem now is that module 'os' has no attribute 'startfile'. is there any module that can execute the kodi program? or is there any path to open kodi using button?

Comment: @luriaz, try to replace `os.startfile('/usr/share/applications/kodi.desktop')` with `from subprocess import call; call(['kodi'])`.

Comment: the external program is able to launch. thank you. why use call from subprocess module instead of os module?

Comment: @luriaz, `subprocess` module is just more "powerful" for this means. Though you also could use `os.system('kodi')` to run Kodi. `os.startfile`, on the other hand, is only available on Windows. 
P.S. If you find this answer helpful, please, consider selecting it as the "Best answer".